# Форма с помощью пост запроса

Tags: post, rest, form, auth, postman

Делаю отправку сообщений, и оно сделано через форму. Но вместе с ожидаемыми параментрами отправляется каждый раз странное разное значение[image: Вот фото даты]

С помощью запросов, сообщение не отправляется. Буду благодарен за помощь.
Заранее спасибо!

Upd:
html формы https://pastebin.com/JamL2ahq
Скрипт, который отвечает за https://pastebin.com/G1eegiGi

Comment: Так может саму форму покажете или нужно угадывать?

Comment: HTML код или как выглядит?

Comment: Само собой что HTML и JS код который имеет отношение к отправке формы, потому-то что внешний вид формы вообще не имеет никакого значения в данном случае.

Comment: добавил новые изменения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял, что не так. Тип запроса был не тот